# Fetch data with column alias from related table in laravel

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5

There are two tables

category 
id| name

Product 
id|category_id|name

`id` is the foreign key for `Category_id` in Product table

When fetching data from this table using the following query :

```
        $results = Product::with('Category')->select('id as i')->paginate(10) ;
```

The data is received in the following format

```js
current_page: 2
data: [{id: 3, name: "ssdfsdfasd"  , color: "ewr",…},…]
0: {id: 3,  name: "ssdfsdfasd",category:{name :"cat1" ,id:2} 
count: 3
```

But I need data in the following format

```js
0: {id: 3,  name: "ssdfsdfasd",category_name :"cat1" ,category_id:2}
```

Tried using select as in above mentioned code but received a similar response

Comment: Which `id` are you referring to here `select('id as i')`? Is that the `id` from `Product` table? You may have to work with QueryBuilder https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Comment: @mishka Using eager loading with the alias as the result of other table is in nested form. I tried both the tables such as category.id which resulted to table mentioned and product.id which returned the id of product. but I want to receive the data in 1 D array